# Minted doesn't break the line at the desired character

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I'm writing a document using minted. I installed Python, pygmentize, everything works great. But there is a behaviour I don't understand. I want to break the text inside the minted environment at the character '|'. When I try to do it at

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakafter=|]{python}
some_string = 'SomeTextThat|GoesOnAndOnForSoLong|ThatItCouldNeverFitOnOneLine'
\end{minted}
```

LaTeX breaks the line right after the second |. But with this piece of code instead

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakafter=|]{bash}
tail -n 39 $target | awk '{print($NF" "$0)}' | sort -g -t@ -k2 | cut -f2- -d' ' > /tmp/\ /"$NEWFILE" #@15
\end{minted}
```

it doesn't work, breaking the line after the last space before going out of the box.
[image]
Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `breakafter` and `breakbefore` options allow specifying break locations *in addition* to spaces, rather than *instead* of spaces. You can disable spaces as break locations. One way to do this is to set spaces as visible and then define the space character as an (invisible) non-breaking space. You will probably also want to turn off pre-break symbols in a case like this (`breakaftersymbolpre`).

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakafter=|, showspaces, space=~, breakaftersymbolpre={}]{bash}
tail -n 39 $target | awk '{print($NF" "$0)}' | sort -g -t@ -k2 | cut -f2- -d' ' > /tmp/\ /"$NEWFILE" #@15
\end{minted}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your workaround but it looks like it doesn't work. I copypasted your comment but it doesn't break after '|'. The line is typeset on a single line going outside the sheet. The 'issue' looks like belongs to 'showspaces': if I take it away it breaks after the spaces but at least it doesn't print on a single line.

Comment: @RaffaelloCørsini You might try updating your packages. If you don't have a relatively recent `minted` and `fvextra`, this won't work.

Comment: You were right, I updated the packages and now the code does what it was supposed to do. Thanks again.